# gradle 2.8 com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

I have been developing apps in `Android Studio 1.5.1`, but this error is new to me and I have tried many solutions from stackoverflow, none works. Maybe this is a compatibility issue, related to SDK and JDK configuration.
This is accompanied by one more error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I am posting my app's `build.gradle` file, please help me how to resolve this. It has already taken 3 days.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "app.wae.com.wae_aprofessionaltrainingexpert"
    minSdkVersion 7
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
}
dependencies {
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(':mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

and this is settings.gradle

```
include ':app', ':mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin'
```

I have been using `Android Studio 1.5.1`, tried using `SDK 24` but switched back to `23`, and `JDK 7`.

Comment: I don't understand why you need a MySQL Connector for an Android application.

Comment: it was to connect the app to MySQL database, as i need to insert and fetch data from MySQL servers, in the app.

Comment: You should consider having a server as a middleware, and communicate with that using REST.

Comment: Yes, I had been using xamp server, but this code doesn't deals much with servers, mysql is just imported and not used in the project. Does version compatibility is affected by the jar files?